# Git work on the same branch after merging (discution)

Tags: git

I have created a branch for a feature (`feat/logs_work` - working on logs), I have merged it. Now I want to work on the same branch (improving logs). Is this a bad practice? Shall I create a new branch or work on the same?

If working on the same:

- I have something like this:

  ```
  *   e534410 (HEAD, origin/master, master) merged
  |\
  | * 4f87921 (origin/feat/logs_work, feat/logs_work) Work 6
  | * 8e2f2a3 Work 5
  | * 1f08e04 Work 4
  | * 2a13fcd Work 3
  | * 66ec996 Work 2
  | * 8bccdde Work 1
  |/  
  *   30b9275 Previous merged
  ```

How is better to do:

- If I do a checkout to the `feat/logs_work`, will it do something like: `(**)`

  ```
    *  XXXXXXX (HEAD, feat/logs_work) New work
  * |  e534410 (origin/master, master) merged
  |\|
  | * 4f87921 (origin/feat/logs_work, feat/logs_work) Work 6
  | * 8e2f2a3 Work 5
  ```

  ?
- I would prefer something like this:

  ```
    *  XXXXXXX (HEAD, feat/logs_work) New work (adding more logs)
   /
  *   e534410 (origin/master, master) merged
  |\
  | * 4f87921 (origin/feat/logs_work, feat/logs_work) Work 6
  | * 8e2f2a3 Work 5
  ```

because I will ad some more logs and that is why I would prefer to work on the same `feat/logs_work` branch. Is this bad? Shall I create a new branch ad close the other? Shall I go like in the `(**)` case? I would like some advices.

Comment: Branch in a git is just a *pointer* with a unique name to a particular changeset. Given that, you cannot have a branch pointing to 2 different changesets.

Comment: So you are saying that what I prefer is not possible, except if I close the branch (or delete it) ad create it again? Anyway, is the `(**)` case similar to what I want?

Comment: " except if I close the branch (or delete it) ad create it again" --- that's right. "similar to what I want" --- you tell us if it looks like what you want.

Comment: You can choose either workflow. Git does not care and won't have any troubles when you are merging a branch multiple times.

Comment: @zerkms: yes, that is what I wanted to say

Comment: @knittl: And if I do some other changes then I have to merge master in feat/... (for having the latest changes) and fix conflicts and continue working on the feat branch?

Comment: If you need the changes from master in feat you have to merge master into feat. If you need changes from feat in master, you have to merge feat into master.

Comment: What do you think of my answer? Is it the thing that I want? Or is it something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possibility is to do a merge of `master` into `feat/logs_work`, and have something like below:

```
      *  XXXXXXX (HEAD, feat/logs_work) New work
     /|
    * |  e534410 (origin/master, master) merged
    |\|
    | * 4f87921 (origin/feat/logs_work, feat/logs_work) Work 6
    | * 8e2f2a3 Work 5
```

I know that for my case is not very different/important, but if I have done some other changes on `master` this will update the `feat/logs_work` branch:

```
      *  XXXXXXX (HEAD, feat/logs_work) New work
     /|
    * |  QQQQQQQ (origin/master, master) some other commit on master or some other merge
    * |  e534410 merged
    |\|
    | * 4f87921 (origin/feat/logs_work, feat/logs_work) Work 6
    | * 8e2f2a3 Work 5
```

Comment: Please comment with your opinions about this